# LuaLaTeX and listings do not work while XeLaTex works fine

Tags: xetex, listings, luatex, mactex

I am trying to move from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX. I have some listings with special delimeters (an underscore). The following MWE compiles perfectly under XeLaTex, but gives the following error under LuaLaTeX:

**Error Message**:

```
./plots.tex:36: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
$
l.36 TABLE1(_ID1_
               ,DATA1)
? 
Process aborted
```

**MWE**:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    language=SQL,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\small\ttfamily\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=t,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=4,
    moredelim=[is][\underbar]{_}{_},
    moredelim=**[is][\bfseries]{@}{@},
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}
}
\begin{document}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Database Tables, label={lst:tables}]
TABLE1(_ID1_,DATA1)
TABLE1(_ID2_,DATA2)
TABLE3(_ID3_,DATA3)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

**Additional Info**:

1. I'm using MacTeX 2014.
2. I tried to use the `underscore` package, but
   that didn't help.
3. I tried to change the delimeter, and that didn't
   help neither.

Comment: I get the same errors in XeLaTeX and in LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `\underbar` command in your `moredelim` setting: With `unicode-math` it is a math command. You could use e.g. the `ulem` package and `\uline` instead:

```
\usepackage{ulem}
...

`moredelim=[is][\uline]{_}{_},`
```

Comment: Why not `\underline` without any package?

Comment: @egreg: Why easy when you can do it in a complicated way? ;-). Actually I tried `\underline`but got an error due to an `\underbar` still lurking around and so thought that `\underline` has the same problem.