# Possible Lualatex problem with documentation library from tcolorbox

Tags: listings, luatex, tcolorbox

I am developping a package which uses some `lualatex` features. In order to show examples in the documentation, I have to use `lualatex` for the compilation as well. I decided to use the `documentation` library from the `tcolorbox` package, however this fails, if I want to use `lualatex`.
The compilation stops with this error message right at the start (i.e. in the preamble phase)

```
 ! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.52     moredelim={[is][\itshape\rmfamily]{
                                          �}{�}},
```

The additional `tcolorbox` libraries `listings` or `listingsutf8` did not help. Since `documentation` is based on those libraries (as far as I understand it) I suspect however that this unhealthy feature has it's origin in the listings package (the `moredelim` error is some indicator)

I tried the solution to a similar problem ([LuaLaTeX and listings do not work while XeLaTex works fine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203984/lualatex-and-listings-do-not-work-while-xelatex-works-fine)), but it does not improve the situation.

I don't claim this is a bug of `tcolorbox` or `listings.sty` really.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[documentation]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: The error message seems to be generated by two non-UTF8-encoded characters present in line 52 of the file `tcbdocumentation.code.tex`. Not sure if this helps, though.

Comment: @Mico: So we should notify the package author, T.F. Sturm? Thanks for looking ;-)

Comment: It might be a place to start.

Comment: Replacing the two § with `^^a7` in `tcbdocumentation.code.tex` should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks, I sent a mail to T.F.Sturm

Comment: @ChristianHupfer My email will be offline until end of the week, but now I've read the problem here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Replacing § with `^^a7` seems to be the right thing. I will test if this gives problems with other examples, but otherwise I will change the implementation. Thank you!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I will fix this following Ulrike Fischer's suggestion for the next release (in the near future).

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Thanks in advance. Is it ok if Ulrike Fischer gives a complete answer then?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You should convert your comment into an answer :-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This bug is fixed with `tcolorbox` version `3.35 (2015/01/07)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing the two `§` with `^^a7` in `tcbdocumentation.code.tex` should work.

Comment: This bug is fixed with `tcolorbox` version `3.35 (2015/01/07)` following your suggestion. Thanks again!